# Can I count how many times a number(s) occurs only once in a column using VBA or a Google Sheets Macro?

Tags: vba, excel, google-sheets-macros

Can I count how many times a number(s) occurs only once in a column using an Excel formula, VBA, or a Google Sheets formula, or macro? Honestly, a solution for Google Sheets would be preferred, but I know that may not be an option.

For my purposes, the numbers will scale upwards of 500, some repeating and some not. I am looking for a way to track how many times a number only occurs once.

For example (this would be transposed to a column):
1
1
**2**
3
3
3
4
4
4
5
5
**6**
7
7
**8**
9
9
9

In this example I would need an output of three, because the numbers 2, 6, and 8 only occur one time.

Something like:
int sum = 0;

and then every time a number occurs only one time:
sum +i;

I have just done a very basic course for java one time, and I can't find anything for tracking repeating (or only once-occurring numbers) in Google Sheets or Excel.

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(COUNTIF(A:A, A2:A19)=1))
'specifically for google-spreadsheet
=SUMPRODUCT(--(COUNTIF(A:A, A2:A)=1))
```

Comment: That nailed it! Thank you for your quick response.